# Merged Resource Dictionary folder of images in DLL not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

New to the WPF process here and trying to define a merged dictionary of a collection of merged dictionaries that are maintained in a utility DLL.  I am attempting to resolve the resource location error.

**Error**

- IOException: Cannot locate resource 'ui/wpf/imagelist16x16.xaml'

**Theme.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary       
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/UI/WPF/ImageList16x16.xaml"  />
        <!--Future xaml file references-->
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyStyle"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**ImageList16x16.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary         
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <BitmapImage x:Key="Accept" UriSource="UI/Resources/Images16x16/accept.png"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**User Control Resource Reference**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/BHP_Utilities;component/UI/WPF/Theme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When executed, the Theme.xaml is found as the error occurs based on the dictionary reference within it.  The **build option** for both xaml files is **Page** and the **Custom Tool** property is set to **XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator**.

[image: File structure in DLL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the files are in the same folder, could you try removing "/UI/WPF/"

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ImageList16x16.xaml"  />
```

Comment: This was a learning moment of absolute vs. relative path declarations.  The ImageList16x16.xaml was listed as an absolute path with the leading "/".   Since the Theme.xaml is located in "UI/WPF", the path that was trying to be located was the non-existent "UI/WPF/UI/WPF".  By removing the leading "/", the path declaration became relative which worked to locate the image list xaml file.  Because of relative path definitions, ultimately, all of "/UI/WPF" had to be removed so that the images could be found.  Additionally, the images folder had to be relocated in to the WPF folder structure.